# How to do inheritance in Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have some 10 tables with the following schema

- ID
- Year
- Code
- Section
- Period
- Date
- Status

Each table has a name data_1, data_2 and so on. Now I want to write Hibernate mapping for these tables. As all these tables have the same schema with only the names different I wrote a POJO file with data as super class and all the other 10 classes inheriting it.

What do I do now with the hbm files? Do I have to write one hbm file for each table? I tried the union-subclass, but somehow I couldn't get it right. I am getting a lot of unexplained errors in Hibernate.

How can I write the Hibernate mapping in this type of scenario? I am a starter in Hibernate and please note that the choice of database design is not in my hands. I have 30 such similar type of hierarchies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must understand that there is no such thing as inheritance in relational database system. But there are strategies to map the inheritance structure to the database.

Check out the hibernate documentation at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

As far as I understand, your strategy is "Table per concrete class"

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to choose what type of strategy you want for the inheritance. There are a few options.

Have a look at this [link here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Inheritance#How_to_Define_Inheritance) where it describes a little about inheritance in JPA. Hibernate supports JPA, so the mappings should be the same, ie:

*Note however that this is the mapping type for EclipseLink*

```
<entity name="Project" class="Project" access="FIELD">
  <table name="PROJECT"/>
  <inheritance strategy="JOINED"/>
  <discriminator-value>P</discriminator-value>
  <discriminator-column name="TYPE"/>
  <attributes>
     <id name="id"><column name="ID"/> </id>
  </attributes>
</entity>
<entity name="LargeProject" class="LargeProject" access="FIELD">
  <table name="L_PROJECT"/>
  <discriminator-value>L</discriminator-value>
</entity>
```

Comment: how many hbm files do i need to write..? I am using myeclipse... please give me a sample for my requirement... it just keeps throwing an error.... i would like to use table per concrete class hierarchy thank u.....

Comment: I am guess you have a hbm.xml file for each of your entities right? Well in that case you will need to add it in all of your hbm.xml files.

Comment: Look at the link @bertolami pointed to. In section 9.1.1 there is mapping example